# fire all events that are subscribed to a specific event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I have a listview

```
 <ListView Name="listView2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!-- First Column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="105" Header="ID">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>              
                            <StackPanel>    
                                      <!-- here is the event xID_Loaded -->    
                                <TextBox Loaded="xID_Loaded" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBox>
                                <Popup Height="Auto"  Width="100" IsOpen="True" >
                                    <ListView Margin="2">
                                    </ListView>
                                </Popup>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <!-- Second Column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="185" Header="Description">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" ></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
               etc...
```

Anyways that listview is binded to an observable collection. I use the **Loaded="xID_Loaded"** event on the column to initialize the popup control everytime I add a new row to the listview.

Therefore In my code behind I have:

```
private void xID_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // sender is the textbox

    // I can get the popup relative to the sender
    var stackPanel = (StackPanel)(((Control)sender).Parent);
    var popup = return (Popup)sp.Children[1];

    // every time window moves I want to reset the location
    // of the popu by doing:
    this.LocationChanged += (a, b) =>
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;   // this will ensure that the popup moves with the control
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    };

   // some more code to initialice the popup
   // ...
```

---

Now I want to have a method called  `ResetAllPopups()`  where that method will reset all popups. in case someone scrolls or for watever reason I want to reset all popus.

I know I will be able to solve this problem by:

iterating through the listviewitems in the listview finding the popup control with VisualTreeHelper then reset each popup that is found.

**I think it will be nicer if I could find all the events that are subscribed to this.LocationChanged event handler. How can I execute all the events that are subsribed to the this.LocationChanged event just as if I where to change the location of the window?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think too UI-centric, just bind the `IsOpen` to your items, then iterate over them, no need to get a `Popup` instance.

Comment: If I dont use a popup the listview inside the popup will not show up. I am using that list to add autocomplete functionality inside the main listview. Or maybe there is a property that I can set to the stackpanel so that content outside of it will be displayed

Comment: @TonoNam: I meant that you do not need to get a reference to the `Popups`, of course the `Popups` themselves should stay, just bind the `IsOpen` and change the bound property.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public event EventHandler reset_Popus;

    private void xID_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I can get the popup relative to the sender
       var stackPanel = (StackPanel)(((Control)sender).Parent);
       var popup = return (Popup)sp.Children[1];


        Action<object,EventArgs> tempEvent = (object a, EventArgs b) =>
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        };

        reset_Popus += new EventHandler(tempEvent);
        this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(tempEvent);
  }


  // finally the method that I needed
  public void ResetAllPopups()
  {
      foreach (var d in reset_Popus.GetInvocationList())
      {
          d.DynamicInvoke(null, null);
      }
  }
```